# Setting a system property for the jar command on Windows

Tags: windows, jar, extract, java-6

Our application relies on using the jar command to extract files on remote systems.  We've just noticed that in java 6 Sun changed the default behavior of the timestamps for files extracted with the jar command (what a terrible freaking decision, but I digress..).  Now files extracted with jar used their original last modified date instead of the timestamp when they were extracted.

With a search I found this bid bit:

jar will preserve file modification dates and times during extract

Files and directories extracted from a jar archive will now have their timestamp set to match the timestamp of the corresponding file/directory in the jar archive. Prior to Java SE 6, files and directories extracted from a jar archive were given the date and time of the extraction. A system property, sun.tools.jar.useExtractionTime=true, is provided so that the Java SE 5.0 and earlier behavior can be obtained. The default value of this property in Java SE is false.

From this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html

However, I haven't a clue how to set a system property on the jar command.  I tried using -D to no avail. It seems as if this same behavior is mirrored in the IBM JDK and I need a way around it.

Anybody have an idea of how to set a system property for the jar command?

Answer (score 0):

I found the  link here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

You actually pass -J-Dsun.tools.jar.useExtractionTime=true
Hope this helps someone else out in the future.